# Careers CV print view should show everything by default

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

Currently the "print" view of the careers CV shows exactly what's shown in the browser. This has caused a few of my potential employers to miss:

1. My work history beyond the five jobs that are shown by default
2. **My description of work responsibilities**

Here's an example:

1. Visit http://careers.stackoverflow.com/wolever
2. Click File -> Print
3. Notice that the work descriptions don't appear: [image: example]

Comment: retagged this [feature-request] since this does not seem to be a bug.

Comment: you mean you want this view http://careers.stackoverflow.com/MayankKumarSwami to print ? If they generate resume nwith image that would be very cool

Comment: Ok, try again — I've updated the post with an example.